# Sharing an answer to Gmail (and other mail apps) gives blank subject

Tags: bug, android-app

Using the in-app "Share" function, sharing a question to Gmail is OK provides the question's title as the subject. However, sharing an answer gives blank subject.

- App Version: 1.0.94
- Device Manufacturer: BLU
- Device Model: BLU STUDIO C SUPER CAMERA

  - OS Version: 5.0 (1436245744)

Comment: Technically, an answer doesn't have a title in SE database...

Comment: sure, then it should simply pull the question's title as the subject when sharing an answer ... much nicer than sending out an email with a blank subject